# Pandas -> Read amorphous JSON nicely?

Tags: python, json, pandas

if you query Elasticsearch using aggregations you get something like

```
{
"took": 3,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
    "myAgg": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": 6026519297076008,
                "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
                "key": 6026519683202002,
                "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
                "key": 6026512090922114,
                "doc_count": 1
            },
            **********
            ALOT OF OTHERS ITEMS HERE, LIKE, MILLIONS!!!
            **********
        ]
    }
}
}}
```

Is there a way to instruct pandas to ignore the rest of the tree and only load the child-elements of `buckets`?

ps: I don't want to bring `json.Loads` into play because it uses ALOT of memory (5-8x the size of the raw Json), and the JSONs are about 150MB each... and I will have to handle about 150 of them

Comment: so your bottleneck is RAM consumption?

Comment: you won't be able to do this in pandas with out preprocessing (happy to be proved wrong though), the only thing I can think of is to 1 amend your api call to get child items. 2. open the file in python and strip out the parts of the JSON you don't need.

Comment: @Marcos yes... because this was such a simple json and I really don't need any pandas specific feature I attempted to use only `json.loads`, but in a very short period the RAM hit 5-6GB...

Comment: Agree with @Datanovice, I think your solution would involve manually parsing the child objects. I can't think of any other way.